# Get array Index on ng-options in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to get the index (array key) `ng-options` of AngularJS (1.3) instead of ticketId

```
<select
    ng-options="itemList.ticketId for itemList in itemList"
    ng-model="model.selected"
>
```

How can i do this? I try different solutions but without success.

Comment: Could you add some of the possible solutions you tried in your question?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
     <select>
       <option ng-repeat='o in options' value='{{$index}}'>{{o}}</option> 
     </select>
```